# How to speed up my code using Sparse-array possibly?

Tags: performance-tuning, sparse-arrays

I created  two loops using Parallel table and a table. The outer loop  causes a (nstates by nstates) dimension matrix and the inner loop calculates the matrix elements based on their position in the outer matrix and also the initial predefined array (avec). 
Keeping in mind the avec I wrote here is just an example and always not so simple, and I do not usually end up with a final diagonal  matrix, I want to know how I can make use of SparsArray and probably Associate to speed it up?
I have tried to use SparseArray, but since I need to calculate the elements initially based on their position and I am not that familiar with the tricks to do that, I would appreciate it if someone can help.

here is the example code:

initial conditions:

```
ℓ0 = 8;
γ = 
Join[Table[{m, 1}, {m, -ℓ0, ℓ0}], 
Table[{m, -1}, {m, -ℓ0, ℓ0}]]
nstates = Length[γ]
ne = 2 ℓ0 + 2
```

simple avec:

```
 avec = Table[0, {ie, 1, ne}, {i, 1, nstates}];
 Do[avec[[1, 3]] = 1;
 avec[[i + 1, 2 + ne]] = 1, {i, 1, (ne - 1)}]
```

This is the function I am using in the loop, and probably its at its best speed, so I do not think I need to change anything about this part:

```
 ParallelEvaluate[Off[ClebschGordan::phy];
 ClearAll[j3s];
 j3s[a_, b_, c_] := j3s[a, b, c] = ThreeJSymbol[a, b, c];
 ClearAll[dfxn]; 
 dfxn[ℓ_, m1_, m2_, p1_, p2_] := 
 N@If[m1 + p1 == m2 + p2, 
 Sum[(2 ℓ + 1)^2 (2 ℓtemp + 1)/(4 π )
    Sum[If[m1 + p1 == mval && m2 + p2 == mval, 
     j3s[{ℓ, m1}, {ℓ, 
        p1}, {ℓtemp, -mval}] j3s[{ℓ, 
        m2}, {ℓ, 
        p2}, {ℓtemp, -mval}] j3s[{ℓ, 
        0}, {ℓ, 0}, {ℓtemp, 0}]^2, 
     0], {mval, -ℓtemp, ℓtemp}], \
 {ℓtemp, 0, 2 ℓ}], 0];];
```

and here is the loop which I want to modify the speed using SparseArray if possible:

```
   vex =(*(2 ℓ0 +1)^2*) ParallelTable[

  mpf = γ[[f, 1]];
  mk = γ[[k, 1]];
  μpf = γ[[f, 2]];
  μk = γ[[k, 2]];
  Chop[Total[
  Table[(* Here we loop over the HF states 
  *)Off[ClebschGordan::phy];
  pi = γ[[i, 1]]; 
  pj = γ[[j, 1]];
  μpi = γ[[i, 2]];
  μpj = γ[[j, 2]];
  If[μpi == μk && μpj == μpf, 
  N[Conjugate[avec[[ie, i]]] *avec[[ie, j]]* 
    dfxn[ ℓ0, pi, mk, mpf, pj]], 0]
 , {ie, 1, ne}, {i, 1, nstates}, {j, 1, nstates}]
 , Infinity]],
 {f, 1, nstates}, {k, 1, nstates}]
------------------------------------------------------------------
```

This was the simple version of my program, Thanks to you @Henrik Schumacher I got to learn about packed arrays. But I am still having problem with making it work for different avecs in which I may have more than one nonzero element in each row.
for example if I define my avec as

```
 avec = SparseArray@ConstantArray[0., {ne, nstates}];

 stateList = Flatten[Table[stateA1 = {im - 1, -1}; stateA2 = {-im, 1};
 stateB1 = {-im, -1}; stateB2 = {im, 1};
 iA1 = Part[Position[\[Gamma], stateA1], 1, 1];
 iA2 = Part[Position[\[Gamma], stateA2], 1, 1];
 iB1 = Part[Position[\[Gamma], stateB1], 1, 1];
 iB2 = Part[Position[\[Gamma], stateB2], 1, 1];
 {{iA1, iA2}, {iB1, iB2}}, {im, 1, \[ScriptL]0}], 1];
 Do[avec[[ie, stateList[[ie, 1]]]] = 
 Sin[(ie \[Pi])/(2 (2 \[ScriptL]0 + 1))];
 avec[[ie, stateList[[ie, 2]]]] = 
 Cos[(ie \[Pi])/(2 (2 \[ScriptL]0 + 1))];
, {ie, 1, 2 \[ScriptL]0}]
 avec[[2 \[ScriptL]0 + 2, Part[Position[\[Gamma], {0, 1}], 1, 1]]] = 1;
 avec[[2 \[ScriptL]0 + 1, 
 Part[Position[\[Gamma], {\[ScriptL]0, -1}], 1, 1]]] = 1;
```

Then I don't know how to change this part of your code

```
 aa = ConjugateTranspose[avec].avec;
 {ilist, jlist} = Transpose[aa["NonzeroPositions"]];
```

Or if anyway I can use the same method still.
Thank you again for your time and help.

Comment: Yes, it is certainly possible to speed this up considerably. Basically 99.9 percent of the numbers in the `Table` you `Total` over are zeroes. There should be a simple logic to figure out whether the entries have to be computed in the first place. To point out what I mean: constructions like `Sum[f[i] g[j] KroneckerDelta[i, j], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}]` are popular with physicists as they allow simple paper calculation, but super inefficient on a compute because they require $\Theta(n^2)$. Instead, `Sum[f[i] g[i], {i, 1, n}]` leads to the same result in $\Theta(n)$.

Comment: Another issue (related to that) is that the final matrix seems to be a diagonal matrix. So there is also no need to compute the off-diagonal entries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, here is my take on it, but I give no guarantees for correctness. The basic idea here is to replace summations by logic, to do as much logic as possible offline and to do remaining by filtering lists of summation indices.

```
ℓ0 = 8;
γ = Developer`ToPackedArray@ Join[Table[{m, 1}, {m, -ℓ0, ℓ0}], Table[{m, -1}, {m, -ℓ0, ℓ0}]];
{γ1, γ2} = Transpose[γ];
nstates = Length[γ];
ne = 2 ℓ0 + 2;

avec = SparseArray@ConstantArray[0., {ne, nstates}];
Do[avec[[1, 3]] = 1.; avec[[i + 1, 2 + ne]] = 1., {i, 1, (ne - 1)}];

aa = ConjugateTranspose[avec].avec;
{ilist, jlist} = Transpose[aa["NonzeroPositions"]];
vals = aa["NonzeroValues"];
γ1ilist = γ1[[ilist]];
γ1jlist = γ1[[jlist]];
γ2ilist = γ2[[ilist]];
γ2jlist = γ2[[jlist]];

ParallelEvaluate[Off[ClebschGordan::phy];
  ClearAll[j3s];
  j3s[a_, b_, c_] := j3s[a, b, c] = N@ThreeJSymbol[a, b, c];
  ClearAll[dfxn];
  dfxn[ℓ_, m1_, m2_, p1_, p2_] := 
   If[m1 + p1 == m2 + p2, 
    Sum[(2 ℓ + 1)^2 (2 ℓtemp + 1)/(4 π) Sum[
       If[m1 + p1 == mval && m2 + p2 == mval, 
        j3s[{ℓ, m1}, {ℓ, p1}, {ℓtemp, -mval}] j3s[{ℓ, m2}, {ℓ, p2}, {ℓtemp, -mval}] j3s[{ℓ, 0}, {ℓ, 0}, {ℓtemp, 0}]^2, 
        0.], {mval, -ℓtemp, ℓtemp}], 
{ℓtemp, 0, 2 ℓ}], 0.];];
```

And now

```
vex2 = SparseArray@ParallelTable[
    γ1f = γ1[[f]];
    γ1k = γ1[[k]];
    γ2f = γ2[[f]];
    γ2k = γ2[[k]];
    idx = Intersection[
      Random`Private`PositionsOf[γ2ilist, γ2k],
      Random`Private`PositionsOf[γ2jlist, γ2f]
      ];
    vals[[idx]].MapThread[
      dfxn[ℓ0, #1, γ1k, γ1f, #2] &,
      {γ1ilist[[idx]], γ1jlist[[idx]]}
      ],
    {f, 1, nstates}, {k, 1, nstates}];
```

This gets the job done in about 0.15 s (OP's code required about 100 s) on my machine. For the data provided by OP, `vex` and `vex2` coincide. I am pretty sure that `dfxn` can be optimized further; it still contains summation of many zeroes. But I leave it as it is for the moment.

Comment: Thank you so much Henrik, I didn't know about packed-arrays.

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: I faced a problem, It seems it only work for this special avec. In the main program my avecs can change and in each row I may have more than 1 nonzero number. I don't know how to make it adoptable for more different avecs

Comment: I edit the question with a different avec, so you can guide me if possible, thank you so much

Comment: I guess the problem is with the new avec is that, "aa" is not sparse array anymore. When I redefine"aa" as Sparse array I can get the nonzero positions of Transpose[aa]. But I do not understand why "aa" is not sparse array with new avec although the new avec is itself a sparse array like the previous simple avec

Comment: This is indeed odd. The problem seems to be that the values of `avec` are not all floating point number anymore; for some reason I do not know, this drives_Mathematica_ to the assumption that `ConjugateTranspose[avec].avec` is a dense matrix. This can easily circumvented with `aa = ConjugateTranspose[N@avec].N@avec;` or by enforcing that the values that you write into `avec` are all floating point numbers.

Comment: Another question, in my other potential term everything is the same as vex but I have a different If  condition : " If[μpi ==  μpj  && μk== μpf, " ;  I did "idx = Intersection[
      Random`Private`PositionsOf [γ2ilist,γ2jlist],
      Random`Private`PositionsOf [ γ2k, γ2f]
      ];", but it doesn't work and I don't know how to imply the new condition for my other potential term, I think I may not be able to use "Random`Private`PositionsOf " ! but I do not know what to use instead

Comment: Thank you for your time, I bug you a lot

Comment: Yeah. That won't work. But if your condition is `μpi == μpj && μk== μpf`, then you do not have to cycle over `j` and `f` at all: Just put `μpj = μpi` and `μpf = μk`. This spares you two loops.

Comment: The overall point to efficiency is this: First find out which combinations of indices lead to a nonzero result -- without(!) touching all possible combinations. Then do the computations only for those indices. There are different strategies to do that, depending on the type of conditions. And of course, it is impossible for me to anticipate all of them. I am afraid, you will have to learn yourself how to figure that out in the long run.

Comment: @ Henrik Schumacher  Thanks again, is there any reference to learn the strategies or I should understand them by try and error?

Comment: Well, I think one has to learn them by doing. I don't know of any particular reference (which is not to say there weren't any). I suggest to do the following: Whenever you see a check for equality or nonzeroeness in your code, ask yourself whether you could have known the outcome offline. If you do, that gives you a hint how to avoid superfluous loops. And be greedy very greedy with nested loops; they let your runtime explode.